# Filtering with priority criteria in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, filtering

I am trying to filter Table1:

```
 Table1

 Region             mCode   pCode
 Europa               AD    E
 Rest of the world    AD    O
 East Europa          AE    O
 Outside              AE    L
 Rest of the world    AE    E
 Asia                 AF    O
 North America        AG    D
 Rest of the world    AG    L
 North America        AI    D
 Rest of the world    AI    L
 America              AI    L
```

There are four different values for pCode (D,L,E,O) and mCode can be repeated.

I need to get only those rows where mCode has a pCode with higest priority according to:

```
Highest priority     pCode = D
Second priority      pCode = L 
Third priority       pCode = E 
last priority        pCode = O
```

For example mCode 'AE' appears in 3 rows and pCode are 'O','L' and 'E' in different rows. According to pCode priority the result shows the row where pCode is second priority 'L' since there is no row for 'AE' with higher priority than 'L'. The rest of the rows don't really matter.

The desired result has mCode as unique values:

```
 Region            mCode    pCode
 Europa            AD       E
 Outside           AE       L
 Asia              AF       O
 North America     AG       D
 North America     AI       D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use row_number() to assign the priority per `mCode` and then just filter the one with highest priority

```
select *
from
(
    select *, p = row_number() over (partition by mCode
                                          order by case when pCode = 'D' then 1
                                                        when pCode = 'L' then 2
                                                        when pCode = 'E' then 3
                                                        when pCode = 'O' then 4
                                                        end)
    from   Table1
) d
where d.p = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a window function `ROW_NUMBER()` with a `CASE` expression as

```
SELECT Region, mCode, pCode
FROM
(
SELECT *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mCode ORDER BY CASE pCode WHEN 'D' THEN 0
                    WHEN 'L' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'E' THEN 2
                    WHEN 'O' THEN 3
                    END) RN
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('Europa'               ,'AD',    'E'),
  ('Rest of the world'    ,'AD',    'O'),
  ('East Europa'          ,'AE',    'O'),
  ('Outside'              ,'AE',    'L'),
  ('Rest of the world'    ,'AE',    'E'),
  ('Asia'                 ,'AF',    'O'),
  ('North America'        ,'AG',    'D'),
  ('Rest of the world'    ,'AG',    'L'),
  ('North America'        ,'AI',    'D'),
  ('Rest of the world'    ,'AI',    'L'),
  ('America'              ,'AI',    'L')
) T(Region, mCode, pCode)
) TT
WHERE RN = 1;
```

<kbd>**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fa3eb56eb1445d425a4a90bb629719d9)**</kbd>